# How to use bash to active virtual enviroment

Tags: python, bash, command-line-interface

I currently have a CLI that I built using python Click library. In order to run it as far as I know I have to do the following steps:

python3 -m venv myvenv(or whatever name designated)

source myvenv/bin/activate

pip3 install --editable .

I wanted to create a bash script that just did all of this for me. So I did the following:

```
#! /bin/bash


echo "Bash script for starting and deploying this API's CLI."

echo "Creating virtual environment."
python3 -m venv myvenv

echo "Activating environment."
source myvenv/bin/activate

echo "Running pip install."
pip3 install --editable .

echo "All done"
```

Which running it works, however it does activate the environment in my terminal. How do I get this to run these steps and activate it in my terminal so I can run my python cli script?

Comment: try with full path `source your-full-path/myvenv/bin/activate`

Comment: Or, put the body of that script into a function in your .bashrc